# "Переборщить"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

О сделанном с избытком говорят "переборщить". А при чем тут борщ?

Comment: Подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40796/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c