# Происхождение слова "переборщить"

Tags: этимология

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Имеет ли это отношение к борщу или к перебору?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На мой взгляд, слово **переборщить** происходит от **перебор** с корнем **бор**, а не **борщ**, а "щ" является словообразовательным элементом, без которого невозможно образование такой мощной формы от данного корня.  Существительное **перебор** происходит от **брать**, где приставка **пере** говорит об излишествах. А как выразить совершённое действие, при котором произошёл перебор? **Перебороть** не годится, ибо это слово происходит от **борьба** и имеет совершенно иной смысл. Есть **перебрать** - это слабая форма, а **переборщить** более сильная. Есть ещё однокоренные  **перебарщиванию** слова - **переборщик** и **наборщик**, которые к борщу уж точно никакого отношения не имеют, и без всяких словарей указывают на истинное происхождение глагола **переборщить**.

Comment: В словах "переборщик и наборщик" выделяется суффикс ЩИК со значением лица определенной профессии (банщик, стекольщик, часовщик), поэтому Щ в слове "наборщик" не имеет никакого отношения к корню БОР. Соответственно,  Щ в слове "переборщить" - это не словообразовательный элемент, но тот элемент, который следует как-то объяснить (в данном случае объяснение отсутствует).

Comment: Понятно, что в этих словах различная семантика, потому и словообразовательные элементы различны. Вопрос состоит в том, к чему имеет отношение слово "переборщить", и мой анализ привёл меня к действию брать-перебрать, но перебрать имеет два значения: перебрать лишнего, что является синонимом "переборщить", и перебрать что-то - старые вещи, например. Потому и появляется такое слово, как переборщить. Если для вас необъяснённый элемент "щ" неотделим от корня "бор", что приводит вас к "борщу" - это ваше право.

Answer (score 4):

ПЕРЕБОРЩИТЬ, -щу, -щишь; св. *Разг*. Перейти меру в чём-либо.
П. в похвалах, в рассказе о путешествиях. П., рассказывая о размерах пойманной рыбы.

Черных считает, что "переборщить" — это позднее новообразование (20 век), которое происходит, скорее, не от слова "борщ".
Оно было использовано вместо слова "переборчить" (от "переборка"), то есть превысить меру в чем-либо. Сравнить: перебрать (разг.) —  взять слишком много, больше, чем нужно.

Примечание. По Далю, *переборчивый* — это излишне привередливый, прихотливый.

Comment: Вообще Черных не всегда объективен, но тут ему и возразить нечего.

Answer (score 3):

Да, да. Переборщить с солью и пересолить борщ :)
Переборщить - скорее всего от слова перебор - набрать больше чем надо, к примеру, в карточной игре "очко" :)

Answer (score 0):

Я встречал такую трактовку: это слово является производным не от слова "борщ" или "бор", а от слова "барщина". По обычаю, на барина работали один день или несколько дней в неделю, отрабатывали "барщину". Если барин сильно притеснял "тягловых" мужиков, заставляя бОльшую часть недели работать на барщине, это называлось "перебАрщивать". Мнение Даля относительно "борща" мне кажется ошибочным, т. к. "перебАрщивать" означает делать что-то через меру, не знать меры. При чем здесь "борщ"? Неужели нужно было особое слово, чтобы обозначить лишнее в тарелке? А почему тогда не "перекашить", не "перещить"? Абсурд получается.

Comment: Интересно, хотя и сомнительно. Дело в том, что помимо фонетического изменения О<А (обратное было бы понятно), в "барщине" элемент 'щин' - суффиксальный. Т.е. в таком случае должен бы существовать глагол "барщить" (с ударным а, кстати), который никак не фиксируется, вопреки вашим сведениям.

Answer (score 0):

> По версии словаря Даля, слово происходит от слова "борщить", то есть лить без толку много, через край, чрез меру. Историко-этимологический словарь указывает на другое происхождение слова "переборщить" - "переборка", "переборчить", то есть быть чересчур привередливым, прихотливым. ([Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C))